# Move a React element within the DOM hierarchy while keeping state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a small code experiment - a React based text editor, with a component `<TextEditor />` which keeps its text and other information in state. When the user presses the keyboard shortcut for 'split editor', I replace it with an element like:

```js
<Split
  left={this.editors[0]}
  right={this.editors[1]} />
```

Where editors is an array like `this.editors = [<TextEditor />, <TextEditor />]` setup in the constructor of the parent `<App />` element.

However, when switching from rendering `this.editors[0]` to a split with `this.editors[0]` as the left element, the editor looses state (clearing its text), even though the actual JSX I'm rendering comes from the same element in the array.

How can I move a React element deeper into the hierarchy without loosing state?

The actual code for rendering the app is like this:

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import Split from './Components/Split'
import TextEditor from './Components/TextEditor'

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      editorPanes: 0
    }

    this.openNewPanel = this.openNewPanel.bind(this)
    this.editors = [<TextEditor openNewPanel={this.openNewPanel} />]
  }

  getJSXForPane (p) {
    if (typeof p === 'number') {
      return this.editors[p]
    } else {
      return (
        <Split
          vertical={p.vertical}
          left={this.getJSXForPane(p.left)}
          right={this.getJSXForPane(p.right)}
        />
      )
    }
  }

  openNewPanel () {
    const newEditorId = this.editors.length
    this.editors.push(<TextEditor openNewPanel={this.openNewPanel} />)
    this.setState({
      editorPanes: {
        vertical: true,
        left: this.state.editorPanes,
        right: newEditorId
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.getJSXForPane(this.state.editorPanes)}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `However, when switching from rendering this.editors[0] to a split with this.editors[0] as the left element` When switching from what? You didn't show us what your code looks like in the former case

Comment: Sorry, I meant as in the render method of the `<App />` parent just returining `this.editors[0]`, as opposed to returning the split element you can see in the code snippet.

Comment: Put your actual code in the question please. You have two ways of rendering `this.editors[0]`, one with a split and, presumably, one without, and at some point you switch between them. So just put your code in the question.

Comment: I've added a more complete example. (I did miss out some unrelated code such as loading the theme CSS, but didn't omitt anything required for rendering the split editors)

Comment: Does the `TextEditor` component store its own state?

Comment: Yes, they keep a buffer of the currently typed text. When splitting the editor, their state clears and I'm left with two panes of empty editors, despite the one that used to have text in it being rendered from the same JSX element.

Comment: Probably, you should look into React Context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component